# how to send images through axios using gridfs?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, post, axios, gridfs

how can i send a file/image in reactjs uploaded through an  to the backend, using axios?
the simple input form is this :

```
<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitFunc)}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <input
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              alt="file"
              name="file"
              id="file"
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Button
          type="submit"
        >
          Add
        </Button>
      </form>
```

the submit function:

```
try {
  await axios
    .post(`http://localhost:5000/addPic`, data, {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
      },
    })
      }
    );
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error");
}
```

i tried this but it's not working, and i dont know why, because when i use postman to send an image to the same api, it works :

also when i use a view engine and use a form with `method="POST"` in the backend, it works!
here's the api code :

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

let gfs;

conn.once("open", () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
});
let tempNameFile;
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        tempNameFile = filename;
        console.log(tempNameFile);
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(tempNameFile);
  res.send("good to go");
});
```

**to sum up all of this, my question is how can i upload an image to the frontend using a simple input and send it through axios, the same way postman sends an image to the backend to be handled by gridfs and stored in the mongodb database**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Postman worked, your backend is setup properly. Now on to your frontend.

Axios handles multipart form data if your data is an instance of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

1. In your component you can set a state variable to hold the selected file

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
```

2. Add an `onInput` to your `<input />` field like so:

```
<input onInput={e => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])} />
```

3. In the submit function, wrap the file in a FormData and submit with Axios

```
try {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", selectedFile);
  await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/addPic`, data);
  /* Do something if upload was successful */
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: thanks man, it didnt work at first, but it worked after i changed onChange to onInput, i think you should change it, so that i can accept your answer

Comment: @oubaydos Kindly mark as accepted if it solved the issue. Thanks...